# PowerShellscript, bad file encoding conversation

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, iconv

I have a PowerShell script for the conversation of file character encoding.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:/test/data -Recurse -Include *.txt |
ForEach-Object {
  $inFileName = $_.DirectoryName + '\' + $_.name
  $outFileName = $inFileName + "_utf_8.txt"
  Write-Host "windows-1251 to utf-8: " $inFileName -> $outFileName  
  E:\bin\iconv\iconv.exe -f cp1251 -t utf-8 $inFileName > $outFileName
}
```

But instead of utf-8 it converts file character encoding into utf-16. When I invoke the iconv utility from command line it works fine.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you redirect output to a file, Powershell is using Unicode as the default encoding. Instead of using the redirection operator, you can pipe to `Out-File` with a `-Encoding UTF8` switch.

```
E:\bin\iconv\iconv.exe -f cp1251 -t utf-8 $inFileName | Out-File -FilePath $outFileName -Encoding UTF8
```

The following TechNet article has more information (equivalent to `Get-Help Out-File -full` in Powershell v2).

- [Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315303.aspx)

In case it helps your scenario at all, it's worth noting that you can use Powershell to do the encoding conversion also.

```
Get-Content $inFileName -Encoding ASCII |
Out-File -FilePath $outFileName -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Are you sure there is such a parameter for the Get-Content cmdlet as -Encoding?

Comment: @Gustav.Calder - Yeah there is

Comment: @Gustav.Calder There is, but it doesn't appear in the help for `Get-Content` because it's a dynamic parameter provided by the FileSystem provider. You can find more information in `Get-Help FileSystem`.