# Automatic import Google Play Console reports from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery

Tags: powershell, cmd, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-play-console

Google Play Console reports are using UTF-16 encoding, BigQuery - UTF-8.

How I can automatic converting the CSV files from UTF-16 to UTF-8?

My code in PowerShell:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Date.ToString('yyyy-MM') 
$date2 = $date.Replace('-', '')

$typefile = 'app_version'

$table = $typefile + '$' + $date2 + '01'
$csv_file = 'gs://pubsite_prod_rev_******_'+ $date2 + '_' + $typefile + '.csv'
$csv_file2 = $date2 + '_' + $typefile + '.csv'

& gsutil cp $csv_file C:\***\Scripts\gc\$csv_file2
& bq load --replace report.$table C:\***\Scripts\gc\$csv_file2
```

Error:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'majestic-cairn-****:bqjob_r171ebea2_*****_1': Error while reading
data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1;
errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.
Failure details:
- file-00000000: Error while reading data, error message: Too many
values in row starting at position: 0.
```

Comment: `(Get-Content -Path $Path) | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Encoding UTF8`

Answer (score 0):

As `TheIncorrigible1` mentioned, can use Powershell to do the encoding conversion

```
(Get-Content -Path $Path) | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Encoding UTF8
```

this command will convert CSV files from `UTF-16` to `UTF-8` in. You may have to specify the encoding in the first command as this

```
(Get-Content -Path $Path -Encoding UTF16) | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Encoding UTF8`
```

There is a detailed answer from `ajk` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585548/powershellscript-bad-file-encoding-conversation)